# How can I combine shorthands of bibliographical entries with acronyms in text?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, acronyms

I would like to make \printshorthands for the code below and to put put acronyms used in text in the same list with bibliographical shorthands.
Could somebody help?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tocloft}



\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}



\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3.5cm}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}



\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,citepages=suppress,sorting=nty,babel=other]{biblatex}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  pages = {pp\adddot},
}

\newbibmacro*{cite:xref}{%
    \ifciteseen
        {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
        {\ifentrytype{periodical}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:short}\usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\xrefcite}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:xref}}
    {}
    {}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
    \iffieldundef{xref}
        {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
            {}
            {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
                \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
                \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
                \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
        {\entrydata{\thefield{xref}}{%
            \ifboolexpr{
                test {\iffieldundef{title}}
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
            }
            {}
            {\printtext[title]{\printfield[titlecase]{title}%
                \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
                \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{version}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \ifthenelse{\ifbibliography\OR\iffieldundef{xref}}
        {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
            \newunit
            \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
            \newunit
            \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}{\printfield{issn}}{}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
            \usebibmacro{pageref}%
            \usebibmacro{finentry}}%
        {\xrefcite{\thefield{xref}}%
            \ifciteseen{}{%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{issue+date}}}}

\newbibmacro*{in:collection}{%
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}{\printfield{volume}\printfield{part}}{}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}{\printfield{isbn}}{}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \iffieldundef{xref}
        {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{in:collection}}%
        {\ifcitation
            {\xrefcite{\thefield{xref}}}
            {\entrydata{\thefield{xref}}{%
                \usebibmacro{title}%
                \newunit\newblock
                \usebibmacro{in:collection}}}}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{in:proceedings}{%
    \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}{\printfield{volume}\printfield{part}}{}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printlist{organization}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}{\printfield{isbn}}{}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \iffieldundef{xref}
        {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
            \newunit\newblock
            \usebibmacro{in:proceedings}}%
        {\ifcitation
            {\xrefcite{\thefield{xref}}}
            {\entrydata{\thefield{xref}}{%
                \usebibmacro{title}%
                \newunit\newblock
                \usebibmacro{in:proceedings}}}}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\bibliography{test}
\frenchspacing


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Inproceedings{Science:Environment2000,
title = {Environmental Science and Management in Developing versus Developed Countries: education and research perspectives},
xref = {Environment2000},
author = {John Doe},
pages = {23--45},
keywords = {primary}
}

@Inproceedings{health:Environment2000,
title = {Public health: implications from a compromised environment},
xref = {Environment2000},
author = {Ho Chi Minh},
pages = {330--335},
keywords = {primary}
}

@Proceedings{Environment2000,
title = {International Conference on Environmental Pollution, Restoration, and Management},
shorthand = {ICEP},
date = {2000},
keywords = {primary}}

@InCollection{westfahl:space,
xref = {westfahl:frontier},
author = {Westfahl, Gary},
title = {The True Frontier},
subtitle = {Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films},
pages = {55--65},
keywords = {secondaire}}

@Collection{westfahl:frontier,
editor = {Westfahl, Gary},
shorthand = {FTSF},
title = {Space and Beyond},
subtitle = {The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction},
publisher = {Greenwood},
location = {Westport, Conn. and London},
date = {2000},
keywords = {secondaire}}

@Article{Episkepsis1970:1,
title = {Decide ne plus refuser},
xref = {Episkepsis},
date = {1970},
number = {1},
pages = {6--7},
keywords = {primary}}

@Article{Episkepsis1972:62,
title = {La jeunesse et la preparation},
xref = {Episkepsis},
date = {1972},
number = {62},
pages = {5--7},
keywords = {primary}}

@Article{Episkepsis2009:701,
title = {Reunion a Chambesy de la IV\textsuperscript{e} Conference},
xref = {Episkepsis},
date = {2009},
number = {701},
pages = {8--21},
keywords = {secondaire}}

@periodical{Episkepsis,
options = {skipbib=true},
title = {Episkepsis},
shorthand = {EP},
date = {1970/},
publisher = {Ceneter OPO},
address = {Chambesy--Geneve},
keywords = {primary}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\tableofcontents

\printshorthands



\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Préface}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Préface}}
\chapter{Le choix du thème}
Balah blah blah L'Organisation des Nations unies (ONU) 
\footcite[cf.][332]{health:Environment2000}
\footcite{Science:Environment2000}


\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Introduction}}
\chapter{Initiatives du PO}
\section{Les lettres du PO 1904}
Balah blah blah (ONU) 
\footcite[331]{health:Environment2000}
\footcite{westfahl:space}



\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Chapitre}}
\chapter{Les décisions des CP}
\section{Les décisions des CP de Rhodes 1964}

\footcite{westfahl:frontier}
\footcite[cf.][6]{Episkepsis1972:62}



\chapter{L'ouvre de la CIP}
\section{Les décisions de la I\textsuperscript{re} CPP}
\footcite{Episkepsis2009:701}
\footcite[7]{Episkepsis1972:62}


\chapter{Évaluation de l'œuvre accomplie et perspectives}
\section{Évaluation de l'œuvre accomplie}

\footcite{Episkepsis2009:701}
\footcite[7]{Episkepsis1972:62}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Conclusion}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Conclusion}}
\chapter{}




\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources principaux}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondaire,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources secondaires}]

\end{document}
```

**After correction:**

to have the list like this

> Sigles
>
> EP Episkepsis (1970–).
>
> FTSF Gary W, éd. Space and Beyond.The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction.
>   Westport, Conn. et London : Greenwood,
>   2000.
>
> GSM Groupe Spécial Mobile
>
> ICEP  International Conference on Environmental Pollution,
>   Restoration, and Management. 2000.
>
> ONU L'Organisation des Nations unies

I have no idea which package to use  for it and how. `acronym` or `glossaries` or other one it's not in principle for me.

Thanks

Comment: This MWE doesn't invoke any commands from `acronym`. Can you add some code to demonstrate what features of the package you're using? I can think of one way to combine the acronym and shorthand lists, but it's a hack and doesn't print the page on which the acronym/shorthand was first used. Are you willing to part with page numbers?

Comment: @Audrey :) I've put an example, but I have no a piece of code. Without of page numbers.

Comment: OK. I posted a quick and dirty solution. Hopefully a nicer answer will turn up. Your MWE should probably be simplified. I'd also make those issues you're having with `hyperref` and vertical spacing of chapter titles two individual questions separate from this one. If you want, I can apply some edits to this question. Just let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution only addresses your question about creating a list of `biblatex` shorthands with acronyms used in text. Note that it is essentially a hack that requires you to specify acronyms in your `.bib` file. It also doesn't do anything fancy with hyperlinks or page references, like the `acronym` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{cite:acro}{%
    \ifciteseen
        {\printfield{shorthand}}
        {\printfield{labeltitle}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printfield{shorthand}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\acro}{}{\usebibmacro{cite:acro}}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{title}{#1}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{\printfield{title}\nopunct}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Proceedings{Env,
title = {International Conference on Environmental Pollution, Restoration, and Management},
shorthand = {ICEP},
date = {2000}}

@Periodical{Epi,
title = {Episkepsis},
shorthand = {EP},
date = {1970/},
publisher = {Ceneter OPO},
address = {Chambesy--Geneve}}

@customa{ONU,
options = {skipbib=true},
title = {L'Organisation des Nations unies},
shorthand = {ONU}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
The \acro{ONU} reads \cite{Epi}. The \acro{ONU} published a talk in the \cite{Env}.
\printshorthands
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]